# Delete spaces in textfile and read text C#

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files

I know this really is an easy question but it feels like I have read all post on the internet but I haven't found anything that can solve my problem. I know that Java have a stringtokenizer but I'm in C#.
The thing I want to do is that i have a textfile that looks like this:

```
ProductNr   ProductName         CustomerNr      Customer
AAAAA       Shoes               S111            Shoebuyer
BBBBB       Umbrella            U222            Umbrellabuyer
```

As you can see the tabindex is messedup so i can't use the .Split(\t) and i have also tried the .Slip(' ') but this just splits where there is a space.
The thing I want to do is to delete all the spaces between the words and only read the AAAAA Shoes S111 Shoebuyer and then the same thing on the next row.

I tried to change the textfile so it is separeted with (,) and then I wrote the code below. This works for commas but I haven't been able to apply this to my problem.

```
 using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("MyTestFile.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
                    string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters);

                    FileList objIntäkt = new FileList();
                    objIntäkt.ProductNr = parts[0];
                    objIntäkt.Product = parts[1];
                    objIntäkt.CustomerNr = parts[2];
                    objIntäkt.Customer = parts[3];

                    objIntäkts.Add(objIntäkt);
                }
                //Stänger filen
                file.Close();
            }
```

And in my FileList class I have getters and setters for the stuff I want to read from the textfile:

```
public string ProductNr { set; get; }
public string Product { set; get; }
public string CustomerNr { set; get; }
public string Customer { set; get; }
```

Then to my question, how do i read all the texts in the textfile and delete all the spaces?

Comment: Are you sure your data-items will never contain a space themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
string[] parts = line.Split(new[]{' ', '\t'},
                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Note that if an item contains at least a space, you will have invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regex.Split`

```
var parts = Regex.Split(line, "\w+");
```

This will split on any number of whitespace characters in a row.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make some safe assumptions about the file content, you could use Regular Expressions to parse the line. From your example, there is a certain logic behind product and supplier numbers; you can create a regular expression that extracts the parts from the line. 
For more Information about regular expressions in .NET see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If the words itself  doesn't contain white-spaces this works:

```
var invalidData = File.ReadLines(filePath);
var validData = invalidData
    .Select(line => {
        var sArr = line.Split(new[]{' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return string.Join(" ", sArr);
    });
string validText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, validData);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, validText);
```

However, as soon as a word in the columns or the data contains a white-space the `Split` will  fail. You should consider to use an existing CSV parser instead which also handles quoting characters around text columns like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). Then you should mask them as in `"Umbrella buyer"`.